# Using Volley to download image/video to external storage (Android)

Tags: java, android, download, android-volley, android-external-storage

i have urls of i got as response from a volley JsonObectRequest. What i want to be able to do is save those images directly into a folder on my external storage so i don't have to load them from the internet anymore. Please keep in mind that download may also include videos...

//Here is the volley code for retrieving the urls

```
private static final String endpoint = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/glide.json";
```

//Code to extract image url

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(endpoint,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    pDialog.hide();

                    images.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Image image = new Image();
                            image.setName(object.getString("name"));

                            JSONObject url = object.getJSONObject("url");
                            image.setSmall(url.getString("small"));
                            image.setMedium(url.getString("medium"));
                            image.setLarge(url.getString("large"));
                            image.setTimestamp(object.getString("timestamp"));

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    });
```

Now, how do i request a download so they files are save in my external using volley. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public boolean storeImages(Bitmap imageBitmap, String fileName, String dirName, int index) {
    File file;
    if (isExternalStorageWritable() && isExternalStorageReadable()) {
        file = storeImageExternalMemory(dirName, albumName, String.valueOf(index));
    }
    try {
        assert file != null;
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        updateImageTable(file, index);  // Implement Your own method to update ur DB table, U can access file location from DB table for future use of images
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Convert your downloaded image into bitmap and the save to desired location in cellphone. Then You can reuse image.

```
     private File storeImageExternalMemory(String dirName, String mediaName) {
    String packageName = mContext.getPackageName();
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/Android/data/" + packageName + dirName);

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath(), mediaName + ".jpeg");
    return mediaFile;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state);
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but please bare in mind that i only have url to the image on the server. So based on that, how do i download the actual image or am i not getting the concept just right

Comment: I believe the OP wanted to know, with a URL provided, how do they download an image through Volley. Not really how to write the downloaded image to external storage, which is what your answer shows.